error while runing blender binary on kubuntu 24.04
when i try to run ./blender (inside the folder the binary is in) it shows me this error:
EGL Error (0x3009): EGL_BAD_MATCH: Arguments are inconsistent (for example, a valid context requires buffers not supplied by a valid surface).
EGL Error (0x3009): EGL_BAD_MATCH: Arguments are inconsistent (for example, a valid context requires buffers not supplied by a valid surface).
EGL Error (0x3009): EGL_BAD_MATCH: Arguments are inconsistent (for example, a valid context requires buffers not supplied by a valid surface).
EGL Error (0x3009): EGL_BAD_MATCH: Arguments are inconsistent (for example, a valid context requires buffers not supplied by a valid surface).
Warning: No OpenGL vendor detected.
blender: ../external_epoxy/src/dispatch_common.c:872: epoxy_get_proc_address: Assertion `0 && "Couldn't find current GLX or EGL context.\n"' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

i'm using kisak mesa driver right now, that is supposed to be more updated than the default one that comes in the installation.
info about my sys:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-35-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 7.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 2000
Manufacturer: OEM
Product Name: B75

blender version: 4.1.1

additional info: when i try to open by X11, it shows this error:
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

and by doing cat /tmp/blender.crash.txt:
Blender 4.1.1, Commit date: 2024-04-15 15:11, Hash e1743a0317bc

# backtrace
./blender() [0xf00e20]
./blender() [0x82ae5b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x45320) [0x74372a045320]
./blender() [0xf7e77d]
./blender() [0xf7e7dd]
./blender() [0xf46254]
./blender() [0xf5c400]
./blender() [0xf61a6f]
./blender() [0x717b1e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2a1ca) [0x74372a02a1ca]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x8b) [0x74372a02a28b]
./blender() [0x826d4e]

# Python backtrace


You might have to make sure that the driver you're using includes OpenGL support.  It sounds like your drivers and/or system don't actually provide proper context to the system for Blender to be usable.

Have you tried blender in the official repositories? sudo apt install blender?

for blender 4.xy above it only supports open GL 4.3 and above, and my 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz only supports until OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 24.1.0 so only blender 3.6 LTS and below works.
